# Naming convention of voltage sources in transistor circuits

Tags: transistors

[image: Transistor circuit]

Shouldn't the voltage source \$V_{CE}\$, as named by my book's author, be named \$V_{CB}\$ or \$V_{BC}\$ according to the naming convention as this voltage source is between the base-collector diode?  Also, where can I learn about the correct naming convention of voltage sources in transistors?

Comment: Even VCB would be confusing since there is a resistor in the path which takes up some of the voltage.

Comment: Authors make mistakes

Comment: In general, the supply voltage for the collector should be called Vcc and for the emitter if used Vee.  Because Vce suggests the voltage between collector and emitter Vce = V_collector - V_emitter. So maybe is a mistake. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/355899/how-is-possible-that-with-same-ibase-there-is-more-than-one-vce/355955#355955

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This schematic uses the double-subscript notation incorrectly, and it is unfortunate that this happens as often as it does.

\$V_{CE}\$ means "the voltage drop from the collector to the emitter" or "the voltage at the collector with respect to the emitter".

\$V_{C}\$ means "the voltage at the collector with respect to ground".

\$V_{CC}\$ means "the power supply voltage that is most closely associated with the collector terminal".

The \$V_{CC}\$ supply was traditionally a positive supply associated with NPN circuits and \$V_{DD}\$ was traditionally the positive supply for NMOS circuits, but those designations have become generic names for the positive supply voltage. Likewise, \$V_{SS}\$ has become a generic term for the ground connection.

Source:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_subscript_notation

Answer (score 0):

People seem to have different ideas of how to use this convention.
I would not take it too seriously. Usually you know what was meant.

[image]

[wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IC_power-supply_pin)