Question about class A amplifiers
I am trying to understand the working principle of a simple class A amplifier.
Below you can find a diagram of the inner components.
I am struggling to understand why the gain \$G\$ is given by the formula \$G = Rc/Re\$.

Image from:
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_emitter

Take a look at this answer https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/355899/how-is-possible-that-with-same-ibase-there-is-more-than-one-vce/355955#355955

As an experimental physicist, you usually don't have an electronics engineer as an assistant. Thus, you have to be able to design and understand your measurement electronics for your experiments yourself. Every well-trained experimental physicist should be able to answer such a  simple transistor  amplifier question. I don't agree that this question has to be moved to electronics.stackexchange.com !

@freecharly I've no idea if the questioner is an experimental physicist, but if so I agree with you. So much of what an experimental physicist does can't use off the shelf commercial products and has to be designed to specific purposes. So skill with electronics would be a basic background skill. And much more. For example, understanding the microelectronic physical principles behind SiC or GaN FETs and knowing how that differs in fundamental ways from a MOSFET isn't a "nice to have," but a "must have" just to survive and move forward. But this question is at a level appropriate in EESE.

@periblepsis  I fully agree with you! And much more could be listed here. It seems that some theoreticians (who probably moved this question) often have no understanding and appreciation of what skills and knowledge experimental physicists need in their field.

@freecharly We see eye to eye.

@periblepsis: I am easily convinced that this is a skill useful for some theoretical physicists to have.  But the proper site depends on the content of the question, not who is asking.  Theoretical physicists are very welcome to participate on EESE.

@BenVoigt  I said, right at the outset, saying "But this question is at a level appropriate in EESE", that this is the right place. I was agreeing with freecharly about other things. Not that thing. So I'm not sure the point you are making, I guess.

@periblepsis: Yes, I probably should have directly that comment to freecharly.  Your previous comment leaves open the possibility that the question would be appropriate on both sites -- which may also be true.  But I think you and I are agreed that this is the better place for it, where an experimental physicist is much more likely to find relevant information for designing bespoke measurement electronics.

DC quiescent situation
The base will have a DC biasing voltage, \$V_\text{bq}\$, necessary to properly DC bias the bipolar transistor into active operation.
The bipolar's base-emitter voltage, a diode drop called \$V_{_\text{BE}}\$, is ideally a constant value and the emitter voltage will be less than the base by this amount: \$V_\text{eq}=V_\text{bq}-V_{_\text{BE}}\$.
\$V_\text{eq}\$ sets the quiescent operating current, \$I_{_\text{Q}}\$, due to its presence across the emitter resistor. Ideally, this quiescent current is copied exactly to the collector and travels via the collector resistor to the supply rail, leading to a quiescent collector resistor voltage drop that sets the quiescent collector voltage.
(In practice, the base recombination current robs some of the emitter current before it becomes a copied collector current. But I'm keeping this simple and ideal here.)
We know everything we need to know right now about the DC quiescent state:

\$V_\text{eq}=V_\text{bq}-V_{_\text{BE}}\$
\$I_{_\text{Q}}=\frac{V_\text{eq}}{R_{_\text{E}}}\$
\$V_\text{cq}=V_{_\text{CC}}-I_{_\text{Q}}\cdot R_{_\text{C}}\$

AC gain
A tiny signal voltage, \$v_\text{b}\$, is now added to the DC biasing base voltage: \$V_\text{b}=V_\text{bq}+v_\text{b}\$.
This is replicated at the emitter, with the base-emitter voltage ideally being taken as constant: \$V_\text{e}=V_\text{eq}+v_\text{b}\$.
The emitter current is \$I_\text{e}=\frac{V_\text{e}}{R_{_\text{E}}} = \frac{V_\text{eq}+v_\text{b}}{R_{_\text{E}}}=I_{_\text{Q}}+\frac{v_\text{b}}{R_{_\text{E}}}=I_{_\text{Q}}+i_\text{e}\$. Note that this is just the quiescent operating current plus a small current change, \$i_\text{e}=I_\text{e}-I_{_\text{Q}}=\frac{V_\text{e}}{R_{_\text{E}}}-\frac{V_\text{eq}}{R_{_\text{E}}}=\frac{v_\text{b}}{R_{_\text{E}}}\$, due to the signal. Also note: \$V_\text{c}=V_{_\text{CC}}-I_\text{e}\cdot R_{_\text{C}}\$.
\$i_\text{e}\$ is then copied to the collector and yields a change in voltage drop across the collector resistor:
$$\begin{align*}v_\text{c}&=V_\text{c}-V_\text{cq}\\\\&=V_{_\text{CC}}-I_\text{e}\cdot R_{_\text{C}}-\left(V_{_\text{CC}}-I_{_\text{Q}}\cdot R_{_\text{C}}\right)\\\\&=\left(I_{_\text{Q}}-I_\text{e}\right)\cdot R_{_\text{C}}\\\\&=- i_\text{e}\cdot R_{_\text{C}}\\\\&=-\frac{v_\text{b}}{R_{_\text{E}}}\cdot R_{_\text{C}}\\\\&=-v_\text{b}\cdot\frac{R_{_\text{C}}}{R_{_\text{E}}}\\\\
A_v=\frac{v_\text{c}}{v_\text{b}}&=-\frac{R_{_\text{C}}}{R_{_\text{E}}}\end{align*}$$
And there you have it for the ideal case.

This is what I was looking for. Thanks!

@SleepingOwl132  Glad to hear it helped!

In your circuit diagram, the emitter resistor \$R_E\$ is capacitively shorted by the bypass capacitor \$C_E\$. Thus this resistor plays no role in the ac voltage gain of the circuit. The small signal ac voltage gain \$A_v=v_{out}/v_{in}\$ is thus given by $$A_v=-R_C/r_e$$ with the small signal emitter resistance of the transistor $$r_e= 1/(dI_E/dV_{EB})=V_T/I_E$$ (\$V_T\$ is the thermal voltage, \$I_E\$ is the dc emitter current), which is NOT the circuit emitter resistor \$R_E\$.
PS: If there is no bypassing capacitor \$C_E\$, as is the case in a negative feedback emitter degeneration circuit, then the voltage gain becomes $$A_v=-R_C/(R_E+r_e)\approx -R_C/R_E$$ for \$r_e<<R_E\$.

@SleepingOwl132 I'll add it to my answer.

The question must have been edited, because there's no bypass cap there now.

@gbarry The questioner originally had a full circuit diagram of a capacitively coupled transistor amplifier and the question was posted on physic stack exchange, where I also answered it. The rookie questioner seems to have changed the posted circuit diagram to a much simpler one.

@freecharly thanks for the response. Can you explain how to derive the formula for the voltage gain in a negative feedback emitter degeneration circuit? I can't figure out the currents/voltages.

@SleeoingOwl132 What is you background? Physics or EE?

@freecharly basic physics

@SleepingOwl132 periblepsis has given a good answer below!
