# NPN emitter follower behavior when base voltage exceeds collector voltage

Tags: emitter-follower

I'm playing around with an emitter follower to understand its behaviour under various conditions. In the screen shot below, I have an emitter follower where the input to the base is a 5V sinusoidal. The collector's voltage is at 3V.

The collector's current (top right, yellow plot) shows a dip during the time the base voltge exceeds 3V.

I'm guessing this is because the base-collector junction becomes forward-biased with a current flowing through the BC junction from the base to the collector, and in the process offsetting some of the current produced by the 3V battery. Is this correct?

[image: Emitter follower with a forward-biased BC junction]

Comment: You are correct. Transition enters the saturation region.  https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/276146/a-question-about-vce-of-an-npn-bjt-in-saturation-region/276266#276266

Comment: Interesting; at a suitable bias point, you could use this as a frequency doubler.